# assign a form element to more than one form

Tags: html, forms

I have this small form with two submit buttons, on clicking each button I want form data to be sent to different PHP file. But, both submit buttons are sending the form data to the default PHP file specified in the action attribute of the form tag. Is there a way to send the form data to different files with different buttons. I made an unsuccessful attempt to do so by redefining the action attribute in the second submit button

```
                <div class="dropdown dropdown-dark">
                    <select name="promoteyearselect1" id="promoteyearselect1" class="dropdown-select"  onfocus="showhidephdmenu()" form="promotionform" required>
                        <option value="">Select an option</option>
                            <div id="yearselect1">
                                <option value="1">1st</option>
                                <option value="2">2nd</option>
                                <option value="3">3rd</option>
                                <option value="4">4th</option>
                                <option value="5">5th</option>
                            </div>  
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div> 


                    <select name="promotesemselect1" id="promotesemselect1" class="dropdown-select" form="promotionform" required>
                        <option value="">Select an option</option>
                        <option value="1">1st</option>
                        <option value="2">2nd</option>
                        <option value="3">3rd</option>
                        <option value="4">4th</option>
                        <option value="5">5th</option>
                        <option value="6">6th</option>
                        <option value="7">7th</option>
                        <option value="8">8th</option>
                        <option value="9">9th</option>
                        <option value="10">10th</option>


                    </select>





<form id="promotionform" action="promotestudents.php" method="POST">


                <div style=" position:relative; margin-top:10px; padding-left:44%;">  
                    <input type="submit" value="Promoted" class="button black" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Passed Out" class="button black" form="promotionform" action="alumni.php"/>
                </div>

            </form>
```

Comment: You'll need Javascript or two separate forms to do so.

Comment: I literally meant: <form><inputs><submit></form> and <form><inputs><submit></form>

Comment: How is it possible with two forms ? The select inputs already have a form attribute. How can I specify them to be in another form as well?

Answer (score 2):

Two separate forms wont work, the page will submit in between. You need Ajax to send the data behind the scene without refreshing the page

Answer (score 1):

finally did it with the help of this code.
source: http://blog.theonlytutorials.com/multiple-submit-button-in-a-single-form-with-php/

```
 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
    {
    echo "You hit the button 1";
    }
    if(isset($_POST['submit2']))
    {
    echo "You hit the button 2";
    }

    ?>

<html>
<head><title>Multiple Submit button Solved with PHP!</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">

<h2> Hit the Submit Button</h2>

<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="btn1" />
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="btn2" />

</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button1').click(function(){
      $('#yourForm').attr("action","phpFile1.php");
      $('#yourForm').submit();
   });
   $('#button2').click(function(){
      $('#yourForm').attr("action","phpFile2.php");
      $('#yourForm').submit();
   });

});
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to do this by simply specifying the action tag in the HTML for each of the submit button. I think you have done the same thing using jQuery.

Comment: Even after this code, its directed to the default promotestudents.php 
and not to the second PHP file. :/